# Android - Get list of processes that starts on boot

Tags: android, process, init

How do I get a list of all processes that starts to run when I turn on an Android phone? Not only apps but any process at all, including daemons, services, etc? Given that I want to obtain this list by command on shell (connected through `adb shell` + root)

Comment: This is a loaded question. Are you asking, how you do see them from a program / from a shell  ? Or do you want to see the code that starts initializes android system ?

Comment: the name of the command is **`ps`**.  [This](https://codeseekah.com/2012/10/21/android-shell-tricks-ps/) site has some information.
If you are doing this from outside of adb shell, then
`adb shell ps`

Comment: How is this supposed to help? This only lists the processes currently running, not the ones that runs on startup

Comment: I don't know of any easy way to do that because you are asking for everything that gets started at boot. The code that starts the services is located in [SysterServer.java](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java). This is in user-space. Linux kernel will start a bunch   of processes and daemons. [init.rc](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/system/core/rootdir/init.rc) will start a bunch of processes. But this is not everything. Some of the apps are triggered on boot. Each of those apps can possibly start other processes.